# Insertion sort debug help

Tags: c, algorithm, list, sorting, pointers

The following C code doesn't work (it just clears the list):

```
/* Takes linkedlist of strings */
static int insertSort (linkedlist *list) {
  linkedlist sorted;
  void *data;
  node *one, *two, *newnode;
  unsigned int comp, x;

  removeHeadLL (list, &data);
  initLL (&sorted);
  addHeadLL (&sorted, data);

  while (list->count) {
    removeHeadLL (list, &data);
    two = sorted.head;

    x = 0;
    for (comp = strcomp (data, two->data) ; comp > 1 && x < sorted.count ; x++) {
      one = two;
      two = two->next;
    }

    if (x) {
      newnode = malloc (sizeof(node));
      newnode->next = two;
      newnode->data = data;
      one->next = newnode;
    }
    else {
      addHeadLL(&sorted, data);
    }

    (sorted.count)++;
  }

  destroythis (list);
  list = &sorted;
  return 0;
}
```

Full context: http://buu700.res.cmu.edu/CMU/15123/6/

Comment: "The following C code doesn't work:" -  ahem! What doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit vague because I'm in a bit of a rush. The result is that I end up with a blank linkedlist -- not sure what happens to do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is really to modify the input pointer `list` to point to the memory allocated inside this function, then you need to declare the function as

```
static int insertSort (linkedlist **list)
```

and then return the newly-built list from `sorted` like so:

```
*list = &sorted;
```

As it stands, the call to `destroylist` frees up what is in `list` on entry, but the assignment only modifies **a local copy** of the input pointer.

In other words, in your original code this line:

```
list = &sorted;
```

has exactly zero effect outside the function, but this line:

```
  destroythis (list);
```

does indeed free up the memory that was owned by `list` on entry. So after return, your input pointer now accesses an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Danger, Will Robinson: untested code.

```
struct list { char *datum; struct list *next; };
typedef struct list *listptr;

listptr insert(char *x, listptr xs) {  

  listptr result = xs;
  listptr *from = &result;
  listptr new = (listptr) malloc(sizeof(struct list));

  while (xs != null && strcmp(xs.datum, x) < 0) {
    from = &xs;
    xs = xs->next;
  }

  new.datum = x;
  new.next = xs;
  *from = new;

  return result;
}

listptr isort(listptr xs) {
  listptr result = null;
  for(; xs != null; xs = xs->next) {
    insert(xs.datum, result);
  }
  return result;
}
```